# Partially missing gridlines on log-scale charts in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, charts, logging, logarithm, gridlines

I'm using Excel 2007 to create a log-scale chart of numbers (specifically the Zimbabwean dollar exchange rate) over time. I'm using an x-y scatterplot and noticing one odd quirk.

The range of y values (numbers) spans a factor of about 10^30. On every chart I make using this data, half the gridlines are missing. Specifically, only the gridlines corresponding to the largest values show up. In fact, regardless of the total range only the top factor of 10^13 or so have gridlines. This is not dependent on the log base.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug? I can't find any references to this issue on google or microsoft's bug reports.

Comment: I know this isn't a helpful answer, but I did a quick experiment and didn't reproduce this.

Comment: That's actually very helpful. Either I have some setting set wrong or I didn't provide enough detail. I'll have to draw up a new sheet and try to reproduce it myself. 

I figured it was global because I have exactly the same issue in at least four charts in this sheet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Silly work around as well, but if you are going to be presenting your graph in Powerpoint, you can make the background color of the graph "no fill" and then when you paste it into Powerpoint (I paste it as a PDF). You can draw grid lines and match them up with the ticks on the y-axis. Arrange your graph "bring to front" when you are finished drawing so that the lines won't appear in front of your data.  You can group it all to make sure the lines don't shift while making your presentation and so that they re-size properly if you re-size your graph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, it's definitely a bug.
Try a sequence 1, 10, 100, 1e+12, 1e+30 vs 0..4 and plot x,y scatter, and clearly the scale grid is messed-up even in linear, and in log is the behaviour you described.

My workaround was to make a transformation of the values and depict them scaled down (by a Million factor). That way the data the graph is handling is never above 10e9 (the value I started to hit issues).

So, my suggestion is: graph a Log version of the data (and clearly make a legend for it)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your problem and come up with a pseudo-workaround.

The formatting goes a bit funny, but all the lines show up if you right-click on the axis, select Format Axis.  Under the Axis Options, there is a Horizontal Axis Crosses setting.  Changing it from Automatic to Maximum Axis Value causes all the gridlines to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same thing:  Will not show log grid lines for y-axis ranging below 1e-7.  Have need for dynamic range of 1e5 down to 1e-15.   Tagging auto or max will show grid, but puts axis labels in non-useful place for display.

My workaround:  used Open Office to get what I needed.  Could not find useful solution in Excel 2010.